# How to do testing using cassandra in my nodejs application?

Tags: node.js, testing, cassandra

I am working on a nodejs application. The database used is cassandra. We are using https://www.npmjs.com/package/dse-driver.

I am trying to understand how to write tests for the application.
I am specifically confused about how to keep my test database separate from development database.
Can we create and destroy test databases on the fly like Django?
How are test cases for cassandra and nodejs written?
What are the best practices for the same?

Comment: Broadly speaking, what I like to do is: Have a file that inserts data to database before the tests start, perform tests, remove the inserted data once the tests are done

Comment: @AnandUndavia Should I create a test database and keep it around, or create and destroy database for every test.

Comment: IF you are creating a database for testing, I thing there's no point destroying it. You might however want to remove all the data that the tests have inserted

Answer (score 1):

You can create a testkeyspace where you initially set up all the tables before each test and drop it afterwards.
If you do so, you should keep in mind, that after truncating tables, there are still snapshots on the filesystem. You probably would want to setup a cleanup job.